# How to accelerate python's while loop with Tensorflow operations?

Tags: python, performance, loops, tensorflow, pde

I am solving the Navier Stokes equations for fluid dynamics using Tensorflow (similarly to https://data-flair.training/blogs/tensorflow-pde/).
In my scheme there are 2 loops:

- 1st is a time loop
- 2nd is a loop for pressure Poisson equation

```
# Time iterations
tim = 0.0
it_t = 0
max_error = 1.e6
while (it_t < maxIter_t) and (max_error > eps_vel):

    # Calculate first approximation for velocity
    step_predictor_u.run(session=sess)        # x-velocity
    step_predictor_u_bc_b.run(session=sess)   # boundary conditions
    step_predictor_u_bc_t.run(session=sess)
    step_predictor_v.run(session=sess)        # y-velocity 
    step_predictor_v_bc_l.run(session=sess)   # boundary conditions
    step_predictor_v_bc_r.run(session=sess)

    # Pressure iterations
    it_p = 0
    max_error_p = 1.e6
    while (it_p < maxIter_p) and (max_error_p > eps_p):

        # Calculate pressure
        step_pressure.run(session=sess)
        step_pressure_bc_b.run(session=sess)
        step_pressure_bc_t.run(session=sess)
        step_pressure_bc_l.run(session=sess)
        step_pressure_bc_r.run(session=sess)

        # Error for pressure
        for k in range(n_cases):       
            abs_errors_p_max[k, it_p] = np.max(sess.run(abs_error_p)[:, :, k])
            max_error_p = np.max(abs_errors_p_max[:, it_p])
        
        it_p = it_p + 1

    # Error for velocity
    for k in range(n_cases):
        abs_errors_u_max[k, it_t] = np.max(sess.run(abs_error_u)[:, :, k])
        abs_errors_v_max[k, it_t] = np.max(sess.run(abs_error_v)[:, :, k])
        max_error_u = np.max(abs_errors_u_max[:, it_t])
        max_error_v = np.max(abs_errors_v_max[:, it_t])
        max_error = np.max([max_error_u, max_error_v])

    # Calculate velocity
    step_corrector_u.run(session=sess)
    step_corrector_u_bc_b.run(session=sess)
    step_corrector_u_bc_t.run(session=sess)
    step_corrector_v.run(session=sess)
    step_corrector_v_bc_l.run(session=sess)
    step_corrector_v_bc_r.run(session=sess)

    it_t = it_t + 1
    tim = tim + dt
```

The problem is that inner loop for pressure requires thousands of iterations for convergence. It performs following actions:

```
# Calculate p_new
numerator1 = kernel_2(p, n_cases)
u_dif = kernel_3(u_star, n_cases)
v_dif = kernel_4(v_star, n_cases)
numerator2 = -step_con_tf*tf.math.add(u_dif[1:-1, :, :], v_dif[:, 1:-1, :])
numerator = tf.math.add(numerator1, numerator2)
p_new = c025_tf*numerator

# Convergence of pressure
abs_error_p = tf.abs(p_new[:, :, :] - p[1:-1, 1:-1, :])

# Update pressure
step_pressure = tf.group(p[1:-1, 1:-1, :].assign(p_new[:, :, :]))
step_pressure_bc_b = tf.group(p[0, 1:-1, :].assign(p_new[0, :, :]))
step_pressure_bc_t = tf.group(p[-1, 1:-1, :].assign(p_new[-1, :, :]))
step_pressure_bc_l = tf.group(p[1:-1, 0, :].assign(p_new[:, 0, :]))
step_pressure_bc_r = tf.group(p[1:-1, -1, :].assign(p_new[:, -1, :]))
```

Python is very slow with iterations (I would use Numba, but it will not work with Tensorflow?).
How I can improve my program?

Thank you!

Comment: The pressure equations is being solved using following lines: